# Problema al insertar en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo un problema al enviar el formulario, este no inserta en mi tabla en la base de datos, estoy tratando de crear un sistema de mensajes privados usando una ventana modal de Bootstrap pero al intentar enviar el mensaje este no inserta los valores.

Este es mi formulario modal:

```
<div id="new-message" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="color:#fff;left:-8px;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nuevo Mensaje</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">

          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Mensaje:</label>
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
         <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" id="send" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Mensaje</button>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es mi script en el mismo archivo que el formulario:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['send'])){

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=7MedQZ36mR',"","");
// set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO message(sender_name, resiver_name, message_txt, date_time) VALUES  (:sender_name, :resiver_name, :message_txt,:date_time)");

    $sender_name = $_SESSION['user'];
    $resiver_name = $_POST['username'];
    $message_txt = $_POST['message'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    $stmt->bindParam(':sender_name',  $sender_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':resiver_name', $resiver_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':message_txt', $message_txt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date_time', $date);


    echo "Se envio el mensaje";


}

?>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error?, ademas de que te hace falta colocar `$stmt->execute();`  encargado de ejecutar la sentencia preparada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes corregir dos cosas en el codigo y te funcionara:

1) verifica la conexion con la base de datos aqui no se ve el usuario, ni la clave

2) al final de los $stmt->bindParam() debes poner el codigo de $stmt->execute();

3) verifica si tienes una variable de Session porque sino te dara error esta linea: $sender_name = $_SESSION['user'];

4) El formato que usas en fecha y hora $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"); no es compatible con el campo MySQL datetime por que tiene el AM/PM usa: $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s") simple.

El codigo deberia ser como este:

```html
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['send'])){

// colocar host, dbname, usuario,contraseña para la conexion (como este ejemplo)
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas',"grafimar_admin","anybody2015");
// set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO message(sender_name, resiver_name, message_txt, date_time) VALUES  (:sender_name, :resiver_name, :message_txt,:date_time)");

    $sender_name = $_SESSION['user'];  /// se cambio no se tiene ese dato 
    $resiver_name = $_POST['username'];
    $message_txt = $_POST['message'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    // para del PDO
    $stmt->bindParam(':sender_name',  $sender_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':resiver_name', $resiver_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':message_txt', $message_txt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date_time', $date);

    $stmt->execute(); // ejecutar la insercion

    echo "Se envio el mensaje";
}

?>
```

lo he probado y si funciona la insercion de registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]